# Android: How to update list without list jumps to top

Tags: android, list

I would like to update my list in android with new entries added or removed but when i use setListAdapter my list jumps back to the first entry... How would i update my list so it's position sticks on the same place in the list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question is very much alike the one that was resolved here: [Android - list returns to top after update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660695/android-list-returns-to-top-after-update)

By setting the adapter again instead of working with the adapter itself you reset the position of the list.

Try working with the adapter itself instead of the datasourse directly.

```
adapter.clear();
adapter.add(Item item);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Surely you add the items to the listview and then set the listview to the adapter. :\